# How to derive an explicit formula for $\sum \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{n}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Suppose  $\theta$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.

The series $ \left | \sum e^{i n \theta} \right |$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{|\sin \theta|}$ and, as $\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right ) $ is decreasing and tends to $0$, the series $$\sum \frac{e^{i n \theta}}{n}$$ converges, according to Dirichlet's test.

As I saw in an answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2?lq=1)  question, the sum is equal to $- \ln (1 - e^{i \theta})$, however, I could not think about any way which would lead to this result.

Does someone know or has any references for the derivation of this result?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the [Taylor series for the logarithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x) $\ln(1-x) = -\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$? If so then just plug in $x = e^{i\theta}$ (justified by [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) since you have shown that the series converge for $\theta \not = 0$) to get the result.

Comment: @ElCid I provided a solution methodology that applies to a wide class of series of this type.  Let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give the best answer I can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "trick" that we can use for a broad class of problems of this type.

Let's examine the function $f(\lambda)$ with series representation

$$f(\lambda)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^ne^{in\theta}}{n}$$

where $|\lambda|<1$.  Now, we can differentiate term by term to reveal that

$$\begin{align}
f'(\lambda)&=\frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda^ne^{in\theta}\\\\
&=\frac{e^{i\theta}}{1-\lambda e^{i\theta}}
\end{align}$$

whereupon integrating, enforcing $f(\lambda =0)=0$, and letting $\lambda \to 1$, we find that for $0<\theta <2\pi$

$$\begin{align}
f(1)&=-\log(1- e^{i\theta})\\\\
&=-\log 2\sin(\phi/2)+i\left(\frac{\pi-\phi}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$