# Proof that $\prod_{n=1}^N(1 - K/n)$ is $O(N^{-K})$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove Raabe's test and one of the steps is to show that $$\prod_{n=1}^N(1 - K/n)$$ is order $O(N^{-K})$. The book I'm using doesn't give me tools to do this so I'm wondering how it's done.

There's another proof I've found online that involves telescoping sums. However, I am interested in seeing how *this* proof is done.

Thanks.

Comment: Rough estimate for $K/N \ll 1$: $\prod(1-K/n) = \prod e^{\log(1-K/n)} \approx e^{-\sum K/n} \approx e^{-K \log(N)} = N^{-K}$. The relevant approximations are [$\log(1+x) \approx x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x) and [$\sum_{n=1}^N 1/n \approx \log(N)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). You can make this more precise by including the error terms in the approximation.

Comment: Hans, this is awesome. Many thanks!

Comment: @Winther. Please post it as an answer. I deleted mine which is stupid. By the way, **Happy New Year**. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I would not call it stupid, but since you deleted yours I added a rough derivation below. Happy New Year to you too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 < \frac{K}{n} < 1$ then we have $1 - \frac{K}{n} = e^{\log\left(1 -\frac{K}{n}\right)} = e^{-\frac{K}{n} - \frac{K^2}{2n^2} - \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{K}{n}\right)^3}$ where we used [$\log(1-x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x). Fix a $M > \lceil K \rceil$ then if $N > M$ we have

$$\prod_{n=1}^N\left(1 - \frac{K}{n}\right) = \prod_{n=1}^{M-1}\left(1 - \frac{K}{n}\right)\times \prod_{n=M}^N\left(1 - \frac{K}{n}\right) \\= \prod_{n=1}^{M-1}\left(1 - \frac{K}{n}\right)\times \prod_{n=M}^{N}e^{-\frac{K}{n} - \frac{K^2}{2n^2} - \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{K}{n}\right)^3} = \prod_{n=1}^{M-1}\left(1 - \frac{K}{n}\right) \times  e^{-K\sum_{n=M}^N \frac{1}{n} + \mathcal{O}(1)}$$

The first product is independent of $N$ so it's just a constant $C$ and using the [asymptotics for the harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} = \log(n) + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(N^{-1})$ we have $-K\sum_{n=M}^N \frac{1}{n} = -K\log(N) + \mathcal{O}(1)$ and it follows that

$$\prod_{n=1}^N\left(1 - \frac{K}{n}\right) = C e^{-K\log(N) + \mathcal{O}(1)} = \mathcal{O}(N^{-K})~~~\text{as}~~N\to\infty$$