# Prove the convergence of $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How would one go around proving the convergence of: $ \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n} $. I'm fairly certain, that this series converges, but it doesn't do so absolutely $\left( \frac{1}{n+(-1)^n} \approx \frac{1}{n}\right)$. Leibniz criterion of convergence can't be used, because  $\left( \frac{1}{n+(-1)^n} \right) $ is not nonincreasing.

Note: I've noticed, that by shuffling terms of the series one would get $\sum (-1)^n a_n$, where $a_n$ is a nonincreasing sequence, but shuffling is not allowed since the series doesn't converge absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that

$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}
= \frac{(-1)^n}{n} - \frac{1}{n(n+(-1)^n)}.$$

Now

- $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges by alternating series test, and
- $ \sum \frac{1}{n(n+(-1)^n)}$ converges by comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$.

Therefore their difference also converges as well. One may also identify this trick as the following asymptotic expansion

$$ \frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}
= \frac{(-1)^n}{n\left(1 + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1}) \right)}
= \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-2}) $$

which is summable.

Comment: This is the most straightforward proof. Thanks.

Comment: $ n + (-1)^n = n\left(1 + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1}) \right)$?

Comment: Also how can we compare $n(n+(-1)^n)$ with $n^2$,like I tried $n^2 +n(-1)^n < n^2 + n^2$...

Comment: @BAYMAX, You may need to sacrifice some constants, such as $n(n+(-1)^n) \geq \frac{n^2}{2}$ when $n \geq 2$ so that $\frac{1}{n(n+(-1)^n)} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that 
$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2k+1}&\text{if $n=2k$,}\\
-\frac{1}{2k}&\text{if $n=2k+1$.}\end{cases}$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=2}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}=
\begin{cases}\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}+\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N+1}&\text{if $N$ is even,}\\
\sum_{k=2}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}&\text{if $N$ is odd.}\end{cases}$$
Therefore the given series is convergent and it is convergent to the same sum of $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$ (convergent by Leibniz):
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=-1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=-1+\ln(2).$$

Comment: The only reason I didn't accept this as an answer is that I like the accepted one only an epsilon better. I like the reasoning behind this one though.

Comment: @ViliX64  That's fine. However, by using my approach you may conclude that the series is convergent AND it converges to $-1+\ln(2)$

Comment: How does it follow that it converges to $ -1 + ln(2) $ ?

Comment: We use the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}&=\frac13-\frac12+\frac15-\frac14+\frac17-\frac16+\cdots\\&=-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\cdots\end{align}and this series converges, by Leibniz criterion. This kind of shuffling *is* allowed. By “this kind” what I mean is the replacement of a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ by $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{\sigma(n)}$ where $\sigma\colon\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb N$ is a bijection such that the set $\{n-\sigma(n)\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded.

Comment: I don't like shuffling terms like this though, much less keeping equal signs between lines when the original series converges conditionally.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt When I wrote that$$\frac13-\frac12+\frac15-\frac14+\frac17-\frac16+\cdots=-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\frac17-\cdots,$$I didn't mean that the series are equal; it is obvious that they are not. What I meant was that their sums are equal, as in$$\frac12+\frac16+\frac1{12}+\frac1{20}+\cdots=\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$

Comment: :P Yeah I know what you mean. But it's probably a lot easier to make a small hint at partial sums.

Comment: Oh, nvm. You have a nice explanation at the end. Excuse my blindness.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}<\frac{(-1)^n}{2 n}, \text{ for any }n\in\mathbb{N}\land n\geq 2$$
As the second series converges for Leibniz criterion, so does the first

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

$a_n: \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n}= $

$\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n+(-1)^n} \dfrac{n-(-1)^n}{n-(-1)^n}=$

$\dfrac{(-1)^nn -1}{ n^2 -1} ;$

$b_n:= \dfrac{n}{n^2-1}=$

$ 1/2(\dfrac{1}{n+1} +\dfrac{1}{n-1});$

$c_n := -\dfrac{1}{n^2-1}.$

$a_n = (-1)^n b_n + c_n.$

Use Leibniz criterion for alternating series

$\sum (-1)^nb_n$;

Use comparison test $(1/n^2)$ for

$\sum c_n .$

Hence $ \sum a_n $ convergent.