# Solving a limit of $\frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}$ with taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

Hello i have an assignment and this exercise and can't figure out on how to do this limit with taylor series, i know that by l'Hôpital rules the solution is 1, if i use taylor expansion the solution is 0, can anyone help me with this?

$$
\lim_{\ x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x)}{\ x-1}
$$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x

Comment: How do you define $\ln x$? The result is an immediate consequence of the inequality $\ln x\leq x-1 $ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [taylor series of ln(1+x)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x)

Answer (score 2):

One may set 
$$
u=x-1,\qquad x=1+u,
$$ then as $x \to 1$ we have $u \to 0$, then by using a Taylor series expansion as $u \to 0$ one gets
$$
\ln(1+u)=u+o(u)
$$ or
$$
\frac{\ln(1+u)}u=1+o(1)
$$ yielding the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you i was in circles with this! That makes much more sense than what i was thinking about!

Comment: @JorgeFilipe You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

$\ln$ is defferentiable in $1$ so,
$$ \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)-\overbrace{\ln(1)}^{=0}}{h}=\ln'(1)=1$$
So, we just need to set $h=x-1$ in the given limit to get this answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to complicate matters. Just recall the useful limit: $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t} = 1$$

Now, just use the transformation $t = x - 1$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

with $f(x)=\ln(x)$ we have

$$f'(1)= \lim_{ x\to 1} \frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}= \lim_{ x\to 1} \frac{\ln(x)-\ln(1)}{x-1}= \lim_{x\to1} \frac{\ln(x)}{x-1} =  \frac{1}{x}\Bigg|_{x=1}=1$$