# Suppose $x<\epsilon$, why is then $\ln (1-x) > -\frac{x}{1-\epsilon}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm reading an article which states the following:

> For summands such that $x < \epsilon$, we have the inequality $\ln(1-x) > -\frac{x}{1-\epsilon}.$

Why is this true?

I could rewrite the following (note $x$ and $\epsilon$ are both positive integers and $x < 1$.)
$$\begin{align*}
x&<\epsilon\\
1-x&>1-\epsilon\\
\ln(1-x)&>\ln(1-\epsilon)
\end{align*}$$
Now if, $f(\epsilon) = \ln(1-\epsilon)$, it looks like I need some term $xf'(\epsilon)$ on the right to get the statement from the article. Like some sort of Taylor approximation? Why is the statement true?

Comment: If $x$ is a positive integer, then $x>0\Leftrightarrow1-x\leq1$ and $\ln(1-x)$ is not defined for $x\geq1$. Do you mean something different?

Comment: I'm sorry, I also meant $x < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $0<x<\varepsilon$ you have:
$$\ln (1-x) = -\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t}dt >  -\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}dt = -\frac{x}{1-\varepsilon}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x>0$, The taylor expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ is ([taylor series of ln(1+x)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x))
$$
\ln(1-x) = (-x) - (- x)^2/2 + (-x)^3/n+\cdots
$$ because $x$ is positive this is less than equal of
$$
-(x + x^2/2+x^3/3+ \cdots \geq -x(1+x+x^2+\cdots)=-\frac{x}{1-x}.
$$ Making the denominator as small as possible by setting $x=\epsilon$, we make the fraction as larger and the minus means that we make the whole expression smaller we find that
$$
-\frac{x}{1-x} \geq -\frac{x}{1-\epsilon}
$$ and we proven
$$
\ln(1-x) \geq -\frac{x}{1-\epsilon}
$$