# The sum of the given series is?

Tags: logarithms

$\log_42-\log_82+\log_{16}2-\log_{32}2+...$ 
In the given [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVl58.jpg), the answer is given as $1-\ln2$. How do I arrive at this solution? Thank you!

Comment: "However, many sites claim that $1/2−1/3+1/4−1/5\ldots$ is an undefined value" -- Out of curiosity, could you please provide reference to at least one such site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln (1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \dots \quad $, see [series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x)

Put $x = 1 $ and you get the required form