# Find $\lim{n \to \infty}\sum_{m=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I've proved that $\sum_{m=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$, but I have no idea how to sum up this formula and take limit.
Can anyone give me some tips?
Thanks a lot!

UPD: Our instructor says that we can't use tools that are not taught in class before and I came up with another idea.

It seems that $\sum_{m=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$,

and $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3}+...+\frac{1}{2n}=(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2n})$ - $(\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n})$ and it is about $\ln(2n) - \ln(n)$ and thus the answer is $\ln(2)$. Am I consider it right?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{m=n+1}^{2n}$? And shouldn't the signs alternate? That is, $\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{n+3}-\cdots$.

Comment: Here is my idea. Let $a = 1+\frac{1}{2}+...\frac{1}{n}$ and $b = 1+\frac{1}{2}+...\frac{1}{2n}$. Then $\sum_{m = 1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}$ will be b-a,and $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n}$ will also be b-a.

Comment: The expression you wrote does *not* equal the sum. For one thing, the series is alternating in sign; for another the first term in the sum (with $m=1$) is $\tfrac11$, not $\tfrac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: @MPW Excuse me, but I can't understand. Is there anything wrong with my proof? I can't see why the expression doesn't equal to the sum.

Comment: As written, the sum equals $$1-\tfrac12 + \tfrac13 - \tfrac14 + \cdots +\tfrac1{2n-1}-\tfrac1{2n},$$ not $$\tfrac{1}{n+1}+\tfrac{1}{n+2}+\tfrac{1}{n+3}+...+\tfrac{1}{2n}$$ Note the starting index you have in the sum is $m=1$.

Comment: @MPW But I can prove that the two formula is equal, and I prove it as above. So I'm wondering if there is anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: There's only so many ways I can say it. WHY DO YOU THINK THE FIRST TERM IS $\tfrac{1}{n+1}$???? AND DON'T YOU SEE THAT EVERY OTHER TERM IS NEGATIVE????

Comment: @MPW Calm down. The two sums you wrote are actually equal.

Comment: @Klaus : I'll be darned, so they are. My bad, three times.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, I would first rewrite the sum as

$$\sum_{m=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\tag{1}$$

then recall the [Taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x) for $\ln(x+1)$
$$\ln(x+1)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}x^m=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{6}+\dots\tag{2}$$

If you let $n\to\infty$ in $(1)$, then you can match the alternating series in $(1)$ and $(2)$ by choosing a suitable value for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Consider the Taylor series for the natural logarithm function around $x=1$.

Comment: But our instructor said that we can't use methods not taught in class, we've only learned the basic concepts of integral so far.