# How do I find the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x(\sin(2x))}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

How do I find the limit of

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x(\sin(2x))}$$

I know it is equal to $\frac{1}{4}$, but how did we get that? Without using L'Hopital's rule.
I tried canceling $x$ with $\sin(2x)$ and $\ln(x+1)$, but still got the wrong  result...

Comment: Looks like I need a logarithms course... How do I expand it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x

Comment: Hmm... I see lots of integrals and derivatives, but we haven't touched anything other than basics of derivatives... I got this question off of another student, so maybe we're just not supposed to solve this question right now?

Comment: You will probably cover the proof afterwards, so for the time being just use the expansion formula, $\ln(x+1) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4}$

Comment: Your limit can be rearranged to $L_3$ in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936642, which by demonstration is possible to solve without using L'Hopital or series expansion, but is quite complicated, and assumes the limits to exist beforehand.

Comment: Yeah I just looked... If it's that complicated then probably I should just leave it for now. After all I am no MIT student...

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x(\sin(2x))} = \frac{0 }{ 0 },$$ you would make L'Hôpital's rule twice to have finally: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1/(x+1)}{ -4x \sin (2x) + 4 \cos (2x)}  = 1/4.$$ Hope my answer helps you!

Comment: Why my answer is like this ???? Why latex is not working hhhhh loollllssssss ?!

Comment: You have to put your LaTeX code between two dollar signs (inline equation) or two double dollar signs (displayed equation). Note that the OP specifically told that the problem should be solved *without* using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @Gary ok thx you

Answer (score 1):

here's my attempt to solve your problem without using L'Hospital rule :

**Reminder :**

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}=a$$

From this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion/936642#936642) you can see that :
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(x+1)-x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
We'll need these properties, so let's start :

Let our limit be $\Lambda$
\begin{align}
\Lambda&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x\sin(2x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\sin(2x)}\times \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{\sin(2x)}\times \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}}\times \frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{\ln(x+1)-x}{x^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\times \left((-1)\times \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}
Hence your limit
$$\Lambda=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\ln(x+1)}{x\sin(2x)}=\frac{1}{4}$$