# Is this a valid proof that absolute value of $\ln(1-x) > \ln(1+x)$ for $0 < x< 1$?

Tags: solution-verification

[I used CodeCogs to create the equations in the proof.  Is there any way to directly use asciimath or something else?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAZ5O.png)

Comment: The proof looks ok to me

Comment: You can use Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof with [Taylor expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x) for $|\ln(1-x)| > |\ln(1+x)|$ given $0<x<1$:

\begin{align}\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}, \ln(1+x)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{x^n}{n}\end{align}

\begin{align}|\ln(1+x)|=|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{x^n}{n}|<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{x^n}{n}|=|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}|\end{align}

\begin{align}|\frac{\ln(1-x)}{\ln(1+x)}|=\frac{|-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}|}{|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}\frac{x^n}{n}|}>\frac{|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n}|}{|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}|}=1\end{align}\begin{align} |\ln(1-x)| > |\ln(1+x)|\end{align}