# What are equivalent expressions for the following functions that avoid a loss of significance?

Tags: numerical-methods

1. $\ln ( x + 1 ) - \ln ( x ) $ for large $x$
2. $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x $ for $x \approx \frac{\pi}{4}$

- I know in general that when we have subtraction of two very near amounts, it may lead to catastrophic cancelation, therefore I need to change the form of the functions to a new form that doesn't contain the subtraction. However, I have no idea where to start - I know I have to use some trigonometric identities or algebraic manipulation such as:
- $\log \frac{a}{b} = \log(a) - \log(b)$
- $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$

The answers are:

1. $\ln(\frac{x+1}{x})$ or $\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})$
2. $\cos(2x)$

Comment: It appears that you have the all the information that you need . As your question is currently written it is quite difficult to decide how to help you.

Comment: The classic book Numerical Recipes addresses some of these issues.

Comment: Were you ultimately able to resolve the real issue?

Answer (score 1):

I shall attempt to address the underlying issues.

The expression $$\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)$$ suffers from subtractive cancellation when $x$ is sufficiently large, because $\ln(x+1) \approx \ln(x)$ when $x$ is large. The suggested alternatives, i.e., $$\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right) \quad \text{or} \quad \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)$$ are both *useless* when we are using finite precision arithmetic. This is particularly clear in the case of $x=2^{53}$ were $x$ is so large that the IEEE double precision representation of $x+1$ is $x$ and the representation of $1 + \frac{1}{x}$ is $1$. You can easily verify these claims in MATLAB. For example,

> x=2^53; y=(1+x)-x;

will produce $y=0$. If $x\ge 2^{53}$ then the suggested alternatives both return $0$ when we use IEEE double precision floating point arithmetic. There is a cure and the name is Taylor. Specifically, we can do a Taylor expansion. It is well-known that $$\ln(1+\epsilon) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (-1)^{1-j} \frac{\epsilon^j}{j} = \epsilon - \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^2 + \frac{1}{3} \epsilon^3 + \dotsc$$
and a proof can be found in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/878376/307944).
In particular, we have $$\ln(x+1) - \ln(x) \approx x^{-1} - \frac{1}{2}x^{-2} + \frac{1}{3} x^{-3} + \dots.$$
There are important issues that arise at this point. Specifically, when can we use the original expression and how many terms should be included in the Taylor expansion? These are good questions for another day.

The expression $$\cos(x)^2 - \sin(x)^2$$ suffers from subtractive cancellation when $x \approx \frac{\pi}{4}$ because $\cos(x)^2 \approx \sin(x)^2$ when $x \approx \frac{\pi}{4}$. The suggested alternative, i.e.,
$$\cos(2x)$$
is useful when we are using finite precision arithmetic. Further transformations are not necessary. The multiplication, i.e., $2x$ will be exact on a binary computer (unless $2x$ exceeds the representational range, i.e., the calculation overflows).

Comment: some math libraries have a `log1p(x)` function that evaluates `log(1+x)` without loss of precision when `x` is small, then `log(1+1/x)` evaluated using `log1p(1/x)` should be accurate - I guess it is implemented with the Taylor series internally

Comment: @Claude Quite so. I find it challenging to select the right level of detail in cases such as this where we know nothing about the background of the OP.