# Basic log-linearization

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, economics

In the first equation I can't figure out where the $1/x$ part  comes from...

When using first-order taylor approximation arount $x_t = x$, I just get

$ln(1)*(x_t-x) = (x_t-x)$

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here is a derivation of the taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878374/taylor-series-of-ln1x . Does this help?

Comment: No, I still don't get it...

Comment: The Taylor series of $\ln(1+y)$ around $y=0$ is $\ln(1+y)=0+y+O(y^2)$, as you can see in the linked post. Now replace $y$ with $\frac{x_t-x}{x}$.

Comment: Yes, but $x_t = x$, so it becomes:
$(x-x)/x$
,no?

Comment: You are correct, but this is what you should expect. The first-order Taylor series approximation of $f(y)$ around $a$ is $f(y)=f(a)+f'(a)(y-a)$. The second term will always be zero at $y=a$. When $y=a$, the equation just becomes $f(a)=f(a)$. (This applies to Taylor series approximations of any order.)